# Send LoRaWAN downlink message through ThingPark Community Network Server

Tags: iot, lorawan

How can an Application Server send a downlink message to a LoRaWAN end device connected to Actility ThingPark Community platform?

Answer (score 1):

ThingPark Community Platform offers a REST API to allow Application Servers sending a downlink message to an end-device. Every http request sent to that API need to be validated by a one-time token so that ThingPark can verify the integrity of the request.

The interface between [ThingPark Enterprise Network Server](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/Home.htm) and an external Application Server is described in the [TPE LRC AS tunnel interface development guide](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/TPE-LRC-AS-tunnel-interface-dev-guide.htm).

For a quick test please check our [simple javascript example](https://github.com/actility/thingpark-integrations/blob/main/1_tpNS-AS/AS_nodejs_example/send_downlink_with_token.js).
Don't forget to update the constants at the beginning of the script.

- The *AS_KEY* is the *Tunnel Interface Authentication Key* that you set on the
  [CREATE HTTP APPLICATION](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/Connecting-to-HTTPS-application.htm) form.
- The *AS_ID* is the *Application ID* that you can see once you have creeted the application.

If you prefer testing with `curl` see our [curl test shell script](https://github.com/actility/thingpark-integrations/blob/main/1_tpNS-AS/curl_script_examples/send_downlink.sh).
Please note that this script does not calculate the one-time token. You need to calculate it  yourself according to the [Tunnel interface development guide](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/TPE-LRC-AS-tunnel-interface-dev-guide.htm) or by studying the former javascript code.

Comment: would be helpful to have this information in the swagger generated API docs. Never thought I should google this question. Also the link to "Tunnel interface development guide" is 404